# How to pass initial values to the FieldArray component in redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have an array of objects and want to pass the data as initial data to the redux form's **FieldArray** component.

I looked through the docs for the **FieldArray** component but it is not clear about providing initial values.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to pass fieldArray filed as a array, you can achieve this by two ways:

1.pass a `initialValues` prop to reduxForm HOC config

```
const Form = reduxForm({
  form: 'simple' // a unique identifier for this form
  initialValues: {field1: "val1", fieldArrayFieldName: ["val1", "val2"]}
})(SimpleForm)

const SimpleForm = (props) => (
  ...
  <FieldArray name="fieldArrayFieldName" component={renderFieldArrayComp} />
  ...
)

const renderFieldArrayComp = ({ fields }) => (  
        {fields.map((field, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <Field
              name={hobby}
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
              label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      )
```

see [docs](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/fieldarrays/) for more

2.similarly you can also manually dispatch `INITIALIZE` action,

the reduxForm HOC will provide you a [initialize](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-initialize-data-object-function-code-) action as a prop,
you can use this in componentDidMount,

```
componentDidMount() => {
  const {initialize} = this.props;
  initialize({field1: "val1", fieldArrayFieldName: ["val1", "val2"]})
}
```